# SASPy Remote Server Connection

Tags: python, sas, saspy

I'm trying to connect to my company remote SAS Server, looking into my user profile in SAS Enterprise Guide, i can get the machine name and the port, i'm inserting correctly the informations, then also typing correctly the login and password, but it raises the error "The machine name is note valid".
The code is shown down below:

```
import saspy
sas = saspy.SASsession(java='/usr/bin/java', iomhost='xxx', iomport=xxx, encoding='utf-8')
```

I'm using Google Colab.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a firewall issue? saspy does work with Google Colab.

Comment: Google colab is executing on a node in the cloud? How would it connect to your locally running SAS-instance?